# How can I display a backslash in a TextView?

Tags: android-layout, textview, android

How can I display a backslash ( \ ) in a TextView? I'm using Android Studio.

When I write down the backslash in the TextView on activity_main.xml, it doesn't display on the emulator.

**activity_main.xml:**

```
  <LinearLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_id"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="\Backslash />
     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried `setText("\\")`?

Comment: Do I need to write that in the activity_main.xml?

Comment: No. That's a Java method of TextView / EditText

Comment: Please show the XML that isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `textview.setText("\\")` to print the backslash (`\`) character . (use two backslash to print the backslash)

Answer (score 2):

Back slash is escaping character that can be used for

1. Double quotes "    `\"` to display "
2. Back slash itself \   `\\`  to
       display \

usage example

```
textView.setText("\"");  \\to display "
textView.setText("\\");  \\to display \
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your xml class: `&#92;` .Eg.
`<string name="title">Title&#92;</string>`

Comment: I don't think that it should go inside the angle brackets